# How to center fixed-position, dynamic-width divs [diagram included]?

Tags: css, centering, css-position

I have a fixed-width, relatively positioned, and centered #content div (shown as the outer red box, below).  At the top of this div, I need to place two fixed-position header divs, one left of center and one right of center (center line shown as dashed red line).

These two header divs have dynamic width and need to be anchored on the side toward the center (shown in bold black).  When they grow in size, their outer edge should extend toward the perimeter (shown with black arrows).

I thought I could achieve the effect with something like this but no luck:

```
#leftheader { position:fixed; top:0; left:50%; margin-right:10px; }
#rightheader { position:fixed; top:0; right:50%; margin-left:10px; }
```

Diagram:

[image: diagram]

All help greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [a solution](http://jsfiddle.net/wVMXA/) I came up with. It uses 4 total containers to accomplish what you want. Just remove the background colors from `leftHold` and `rightHold`

**HTML**

```
<div id="leftHold">
    <div id="leftHeader">TEST1234</div>
</div>
<div id="rightHold">
    <div id="rightHeader">TEST</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{padding:0px;}

#leftHold{width:50%; float:left; height:40px;background:#ccc;}  
#leftHeader{ float:right; margin-right:10px; background:#ffc;}

#rightHold{width:50%; float:right; height:40px;background:#ddd;}
#rightHeader{ float:left; margin-left:10px; background:#ffc;}
```

Comment: For this kind of left/right float scheme, could I suggest swapping the right for the left, ie: the right floated div should come first in the code, I believe it works better in most situations than the "normal" left/right code order.

Comment: I tried this solution first due to the convenient jsfiddle link.  It works like a charm.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would do this: (knowing as you said, that the container has a fixed width, let's say 800px)

Position the left div with its right at the centre of the container;

Position the right div with its left at the centre of the container;

Both divs should have a `max-width`.
(for this example I removed the margin, just so you see my point).

So:

```
#leftheader {
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   right:400px;
   max-width: 400px;
 }

#rightheader {
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   left:400px;
   max-width: 400px;
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't work while resizing on a normal document, but if the container is a fixed-width, I suppose that's workable.

Comment: I actually down-voted it based on what I thought was an error (resizing a standard document with your code causes strange results - http://jsfiddle.net/267up/)... but like I said if it's fixed width, it will work. I can't cancel my vote, so I change it to up-vote, even though I find my solution more universal [shrug].

Comment: @Dutchie432 the OP said the container has a fixed width, also, the `max-width` I suggest is just a fail-safe, becasue the container could had a hidden overflow.

Comment: ...right - like I said ... the down-vote was "based on what I thought was an error"

Comment: I ended up using Dutchie432's solution but this looks good too.  However, doesn't the position need to be "fixed" rather than "absolute" to achieve fixed behavior?

Comment: @yajus not really, it only depends on the *absolute* related to which *relative*, in my example, you would require the container to have `position: relative` and then the other divs would be "fixed" on those coordinates.